# How to unit test a dictionary which returns a func?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

My code looks as below:

```
public class FileFormatLookup : Dictionary<string,Func<string>>
{
    private Workbook workbook;
    private MemoryStream memoryStream;

    public  FileFormatLookup(Workbook workbook, MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        this.workbook = workbook;
        this.memoryStream = memoryStream;
        Add();
    }

    private void Add()
    {
        base.Add("xls", () =>
                            {
                                workbook.Save(memoryStream, SaveFormat.Excel97To2003);
                                return "ms-excel";
                            });
    }
}
```

And I am trying to write the test as below:

```
class FileFormatLookupTest
{
    FileFormatLookup fileFormatLookup;
    private Workbook workbook;
    private MemoryStream memoryStream;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        fileFormatLookup = new FileFormatLookup(workbook, memoryStream);
        workbook = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Workbook>();
        memoryStream = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MemoryStream>();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
      workbook.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }


    [Test]
    public void ShouldHaveXlsKey()
    {
        var xlsResult = fileFormatLookup["xls"].Invoke();
        workbook.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.Save(memoryStream,SaveFormat.Excel97To2003));
     }
}
```

Is this the correct way to test a functor inside dictionary?
It throws this error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No expectations were setup to be verified, ensure that the method call in the action is a virtual (C#) / overridable (VB.Net) method call
```

How do I test a dictionary which returns a function? Is it possible?
I can assert the string value which is returned but not the method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing your mocks to the class being tested.

Change setup to

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    workbook = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Workbook>();
    memoryStream = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MemoryStream>();
    fileFormatLookup = new FileFormatLookup(workbook, memoryStream);
}
```

From the error message, it looks like to need to set up expectations, i.e. which calls on the mock objects you are expecting. In this case `workbook.Save(...)`.

To do this, `workbook.Save(...)` must be either virtual or on an interface.

---

**Edit:** after further information provided as a comment.

If the `workbook.Save(...)` is not virtual and not within your code, you must go a slightly longer route to be able to test the object.

Create your own `IWorkbook` interface which implements the `Save()` method, then a `WorkbookWrapper` class which contains an instance of the 3rd party `Workbook` class and implements `IWorkbook` by forwarding calls to the wrapped class.

```
public interface IWorkbook
{
    void Save(...);
}

class WorkbookWrapper : IWorkbook
{
    private _workbook;

    public WorkbookWrapper(...)
    {
        _workbook = new Workbook(...);
    }

    public void Save(...)
    {
        _workbook.Save(...);
    }
}
```

Then change your code to take an `IWorkbook` instead:

```
private Workbook _workbook;

public FileFormatLookup(IWorkbook workbook, MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    _workbook = workbook;
    _memoryStream = memoryStream;
    Add();
}
```

You could then use the same technique for other classes, e.g. the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: An interface of this class Aspose.Cells.Workbook does not exist and Save method is also not virtual. So is there no way I can test the call??

Comment: I updated my answer with a common pattern used for testing code not under your control, this should allow you to test your code.